# Does a Plancherel-style theorem for the Hardy space $\mathcal{H}^2(\mathbb{T})$ exist?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, operator-theory, harmonic-analysis

I am working on a problem regarding Toeplitz operators, and it involves trying to prove $\mathcal{H}^2$ boundedness of the operator (defined in terms of its Fourier coefficients). Now normally when I see a question of $L^2$ boundedness of an operator and some reference to Fourier coefficients, the use of the Plancherel theorem comes to mind. I think I know the answer to the following question, but I just wanted to check:

My question is, does there exist a Plancherel-type identity
$$
||f||_{\mathcal{H}^2}=||\hat{f}||_{\mathcal{H}^2}
$$
for $f$ and $\hat{f}$ defined on the Hardy space on the unit circle
$$
\mathcal{H}^2=\{f\in L^p(\mathbb{T}):\hat{f}(-n)=0~\forall~n\geq 1\}?
$$ 
Why? If you wanted to prove or disprove it, would it be enough to examine the possibility of an isometry between $f\in\mathcal{H}^1(\mathcal{T})\cap \mathcal{H}^2(\mathcal{T})$ and $\hat{f}\in\mathcal{H}^2(\mathcal{T})$ across the Hardy space on the unit circle?

Would any of this hold on the $n-$dimensional torus $\mathbb{T}^n,~n\geq 2$

Thank you in advance for your help and comments.

Comment: Would you please clarify the Hardy space $\mathbb{H}^{2}$?

Comment: In this case, $\mathbb{H}^2$ is the Hardy space on the unit circle (not on the unit disk or a real Hardy space).

Comment: If you are defining $\mathbb{H}^{2}$ on the circle to consist of $L^{2}$ functions $u(\theta)$ such that $\int_{0}^{2\pi}u(\theta)e^{in\theta}d\theta = 0$ for $n > 0$, then that's the same as the Hardy space on the disk. Please clarify.

Comment: I have added in the details in the question